# Docker/Node-red - npm fails to install palettes if volume is on a usb flash drive

Tags: docker, docker-compose, raspbian, node-red, raspberry-pi4

I cannot install new palettes in Node-red if the container volume is located on a flash drive, because, npm doesn't have the right permissions to access. 
Can you help me?

```
# docker-compose.yml

  node-red:
    container_name: node-red
    image: nodered/node-red:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
     - TZ=Europe/Rome
    network_mode: "host"
    ports:
     - "1880:1880"
    volumes:
     - /media/data/node-red:/data  <---- MY USB FLASH DRIVE (FAT32 - vfat)
#    - /home/pi/data/node-red:/data.  <<-- default place 
    user: 1000:1000
    depends_on:
#     - homeassistant
     - mosquitto
```

OS is raspian lite on a pi4 and the usb drive is mount at boot with options:

```
# /etc/fstab

PARTUUID=af3416fc-01  /media/data vfat    auto,rw,user,users,exec,noatime,uid=1000,gui=1000,umask=000  0  0
```

this is the log file

```
2020-01-11T13:20:54.190Z Install : node-red-contrib-home-assistant-websocket 0.19.3

2020-01-11T13:20:54.216Z npm install --no-audit --no-update-notifier --save --save-prefix="~" --production node-red-contrib-home-assistant-websocket@0.19.3
2020-01-11T13:21:08.370Z [err] npm
2020-01-11T13:21:08.371Z [err]  
2020-01-11T13:21:08.371Z [err] ERR! code EPERM
2020-01-11T13:21:08.372Z [err] npm
2020-01-11T13:21:08.372Z [err]  ERR! syscall symlink
2020-01-11T13:21:08.372Z [err] npm ERR! path
2020-01-11T13:21:08.372Z [err]  ../flat/cli.js
2020-01-11T13:21:08.372Z [err] npm 
2020-01-11T13:21:08.372Z [err] ERR! dest /data/node_modules/.bin/flat
2020-01-11T13:21:08.372Z [err] npm
2020-01-11T13:21:08.373Z [err]  ERR! errno -1
2020-01-11T13:21:08.380Z [err] npm
2020-01-11T13:21:08.380Z [err]  ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink '../flat/cli.js' -> '/data/node_modules/.bin/flat'
2020-01-11T13:21:08.380Z [err] npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink '../flat/cli.js' -> '/data/node_modules/.bin/flat']
2020-01-11T13:21:08.380Z [err] npm ERR!   cause:
2020-01-11T13:21:08.380Z [err] npm 
2020-01-11T13:21:08.381Z [err] ERR!    { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink '../flat/cli.js' -> '/data/node_modules/.bin/flat'
2020-01-11T13:21:08.381Z [err] npm ERR!
2020-01-11T13:21:08.381Z [err]       errno: -1,
2020-01-11T13:21:08.381Z [err] npm ERR!      code: 'EPERM',
2020-01-11T13:21:08.381Z [err] npm ERR!      syscall: 'symlink',
2020-01-11T13:21:08.381Z [err] npm
2020-01-11T13:21:08.381Z [err]  ERR!      path: '../flat/cli.js',
2020-01-11T13:21:08.381Z [err] npm
2020-01-11T13:21:08.381Z [err]  ERR!      dest: '/data/node_modules/.bin/flat' },
2020-01-11T13:21:08.381Z [err] npm 
2020-01-11T13:21:08.381Z [err] ERR!   stack:
2020-01-11T13:21:08.381Z [err] npm 
2020-01-11T13:21:08.382Z [err] ERR!    'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink \'../flat/cli.js\' -> \'/data/node_modules/.bin/flat\'',
2020-01-11T13:21:08.382Z [err] npm ERR!
2020-01-11T13:21:08.382Z [err]    errno: -1,
2020-01-11T13:21:08.382Z [err] npm ERR!
2020-01-11T13:21:08.382Z [err]    code: 'EPERM',
2020-01-11T13:21:08.382Z [err] npm ERR!
2020-01-11T13:21:08.382Z [err]    syscall: 'symlink',
2020-01-11T13:21:08.382Z [err] npm ERR!
2020-01-11T13:21:08.382Z [err]    path: '../flat/cli.js',
2020-01-11T13:21:08.382Z [err] npm ERR!   dest: '/data/node_modules/.bin/flat',
2020-01-11T13:21:08.382Z [err] npm ERR!   parent: 'data' }
2020-01-11T13:21:08.383Z [err] npm
2020-01-11T13:21:08.383Z [err]  ERR! 
2020-01-11T13:21:08.383Z [err] npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
2020-01-11T13:21:08.383Z [err] npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
2020-01-11T13:21:08.383Z [err] npm
2020-01-11T13:21:08.383Z [err]  ERR! 
2020-01-11T13:21:08.383Z [err] npm 
2020-01-11T13:21:08.383Z [err] ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
2020-01-11T13:21:08.383Z [err] npm 
2020-01-11T13:21:08.383Z [err] ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
2020-01-11T13:21:08.383Z [err] npm ERR!
2020-01-11T13:21:08.383Z [err]  the command again as root/Administrator.
2020-01-11T13:21:08.408Z [err] 
2020-01-11T13:21:08.409Z [err] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-01-11T13:21:08.409Z [err] npm
2020-01-11T13:21:08.409Z [err]  ERR!     /usr/src/node-red/.npm/_logs/2020-01-11T13_21_08_392Z-debug.log
2020-01-11T13:21:08.423Z rc=255
```

Edit: add complete /etc/fstab line and npm installation log got from webbrowser

Thanks in advance

Comment: And what error do you get?

Comment: I just edit my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because the fat filesystem on the USB stick doesn't support symlinks, which npm is trying to use as part of installing the nodes.

Your best option is to reformat the USB stick to use ext2 (or similar) as the filesystem.

Comment: thank you! thank you very much. 
I have changed from vfat to ext3 as suggested and it worked!
thanks again